# Using Arcgis and OSM tiles in Openlayers application

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, tiles

I created a map object and specified options according to Arcgis tiled map tiles.

```
        var options = {
            scales: [120000, 60000, 30000, 15000, 5000, 2500, 500],
            resolutions: [204, 61, 25, 12, 6, 3, 1, 0.5],
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(479368, 5436618, 698577, 4588478),
            minExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1, -1, 1, 1),
            minResolution: 0.5,
            maxResolution: 204,
            minScale: 400000,
            maxScale: 500,
            numZoomLevels: 10,
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:50100"),
            controls:[]
        };
```

**EPSG:50100** is my custom spatial reference that I saved on Geoserver.

I can use the Arcgis Tiles on my map like this.

```
    var arcgis = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS("2012", "http://myurl/tiles/", {
            type: 'png',
            getURL: createUrl,
            isBaseLayer: true,
            tileOrigin: tileOrigin,
            serverResolutions: [204, 61, 25, 12, 6, 3, 1, 0.5]
        }
    );
```

**createURL** function is getting arcgis tiles specified rule. [Like this.](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_custom_tiled.html)

Arcgis tiles are coming on my Map.

And I want to add OpenStreetMap tiles on same map.

```
  var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "OpenStreetMap",
                    "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/",
                    { 
                      type: 'png', 
                      getURL: osm_getTileURL, 
                      displayOutsideMaxExtent: true, 
                    });
```

But it is not appearing. Should I change Map options according to tile provider?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenStreetMap tiles are pre-rendered in Web-Mercator (i.e. EPSG:3857) and hence you can't get them in your projection, and show it in this map.

You have two options:

1. Tile your data in Web Mercator
2. Download OSM data, and then create tiles for it your Projection.

Comment: may be a solution using proj4js transform openlayers while getURL?

Comment: Proj4 is used for vectors and not rasters. And even if you project  individual tiles, that does not mean that the tiling scheme can be converted